# Allow custom URLs in .htaccess with AJAX

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently working on a music related web app that relies almost entirely on AJAX for handling page content which I am using an API for. When a user searches for a particular artist I am changing the current address to be `http://example.com/artist/ARTISTNAME`.

Now I want to allow that address to be directly accessible where I will use some Javascript to figure out what artist to search for. The problem I am having is that `/artist` returns a **404 error**. I want the new address to point to my *index.php* file which I am attempting to do via **.htaccess**.

Currently this is what I have, which is based off numerous searches and is not successful:

```
ReWriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/artist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
ReWriteEngine off
```

NOTE: I am not using any type of framework

Comment: remove last line and try

Comment: also check your htaccess online here : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/